# Android ViewPager style

Tags: android, android-styles

I'm stuck with my android application. I'm actually using a ViewPager with 2 children in it. I have some trouble to apply a style to my tabs.

Here is the ViewPager:

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/pager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

I'm using this on my Activity for my tabs:

```
// Initilization
viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
mAdapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(false);
actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
viewPager.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

// Tabs
for (String tab_name : tabs) { 
    ActionBar.Tab tab = actionBar.newTab();
    tab.setText(tab_name);
    tab.setTabListener(this);
    tab.setCustomView(R.layout.activity_search_tab);
    actionBar.addTab(tab);
}
```

And the tab's custom view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="0dp"
    android:padding="0dp"
    android:background="#FF0000">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="RED"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And I'm getting this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QZKGA.png

Basically nothing is wrong but there is two left/right black borders and I can't get rid of them.

I've tried something like:

```
viewPager.setPageMargin(0);
viewPager.setPadding(0,0,0,0);
```

But still these borders...

Anyone can help me please ? Thanks !

Comment: try removing android:layout_marginLeft="40dp" from custom layout/

Comment: Same, it was just a test, but It has just pad left the text inside the TextView. There is still the left and right border. but thanks by the way.

Comment: I would suggest applying styles to tabs see [Styling Tabs](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/actionbar/styling.html#CustomTabs).

Comment: When I follow this doc my view pager disappear...